# How to solve this problem with running C code on vscode?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I am fairly new to using VSCODE , what i usually do when i want to compile my code i use the terminal and write gcc file.c -o test and then ./test , and it worked fine until today , it wasn't working anymore i get these messages :

[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MzqY.png)

and when i tried running it through CTRL-F5 i get this
[second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOxDV.png)

and with code runner i get this :
vscode Acc s refus . [Done] exited with code=1 in 0.752 seconds

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you translate the error messages in the first picture so we can come closer to identifying the issue?

Comment: NEVER call your program `test` unless you write the `test` command for the OS. gcc dis not generate an executable, first find out why and make sure you have an exe by using the file explorer or the `dir` command

Comment: it roughly translates to this :

cannot execute <<test.exe>> , the process cannot access the file bc the file is used by another process character Line 1:1

Comment: Ok, so that's your problem. And VSCODE is probably the other process. What questions are left to answer?